# How to remove duplicated/corresponding values from table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table structure similar to this:

> send_id | rec_id

It is populated with the following sample data:

> id1 | id2
>
> id2 | id1
>
> id3 | id1
>
> id3 | id2
>
> id4 | id1
>
> id1 | id4

My attempt was using this query on id1:

> SELECT * from inbox WHERE (send_id="id1" OR rec_id="id1") GROUP BY send_id,rec_id

but it doesn't work correctly, instead it shows:

> id1 | id2
>
> id2 | id1
>
> id3 | id1
>
> id1 | id3
>
> id4 | id1

I would like the output to be something like this:

> id1 | id2
>
> id3 | id1
>
> id4 | id1

I can see what's going wrong, but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good place to use the `least()` and `greatest()` functions:

```
SELECT least(send_id, rec_id) as id1, greatest(send_id, rec_id) as id2
from inbox
WHERE send_id = 'id1' OR rec_id = 'id1'
GROUP BY least(send_id, rec_id), greatest(send_id, rec_id);
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
SELECT distinct least(send_id, rec_id) as id1, greatest(send_id, rec_id) as id2
from inbox
WHERE send_id = 'id1' OR rec_id = 'id1';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly!